# shutil.copy() is throwing a SameFileError when overwriting a destination file in Windows

Tags: python, shutil

I'm using shutil in python to copy one file to another location but it errors with the following message `shutil.SameFileError: 'D:\\Project_Folder\\company_name\\file1.png' and 'D:\\Project_Folder\\code_name\file1.png' are the same file`. This happens only when in a windows environment (not on my Unix machine) and only if the destination directory and file already exist. As you can see the source and destination are indeed different (source has company_name and destination has code_name) The snippet of my code looks like this: `shutil.copy(str(file), destination_file)`

Comment: Is `D:` a standard local directory, not some network share or something?

Comment: `D:` is a removable drive.